# how to partially replace a string in array in APACHE NIFI using jolt

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to always replace

- `abcd` with `abcd.india`
- `xyxvv` with `ind.hello`
- `india.gateway.url/time/123/v1` with `india.ios.gw.url/time/123/v2`
- 'someText' with 'diffText'

presented in website under information array, without modifying prefix and suffix

Input :

```json
{
  "requestId": 1122344,
  "Name": "testing",
  "information": [
    {
      "website": "abcd/122/ty",
      "city": "pune",
      "pincode": false,
      "client_name": 5
    },
    {
      "website": "http://xyxvv/122/ty",
      "city": "delhi",
      "pincode": false,
      "client_name": 5
    },
{
      "website": "http://someText",
      "city": "delhi",
      "pincode": false,
      "client_name": 5
    },
    {
      "website": "http://india.gateway.url/time/123/v1",
      "city": "maharashtra",
      "pincode": false,
      "client_name": 6
    }
  ],
  "ReasonText": "something",
  "Code": "ABCD"
}
```

Desired Output :

```json
{
  "requestId" : 1122344,
  "Name" : "testing",
  "information" : [ {
    "website" : "abcd.india/122/ty",
    "city" : "pune",
    "pincode" : false,
    "client_name" : 5
  }, {
    "website" : "http://ind.hello/122/ty",
    "city" : "delhi",
    "pincode" : false,
    "client_name" : 5
  }, {
    "website" : "http://diffText",
    "city" : "delhi",
    "pincode" : false,
    "client_name" : 5
  },
{
    "website" : "http://india.ios.gw.url/time/123/v2",
    "city" : "delhi",
    "pincode" : false,
    "client_name" : 6
  } ],
  "ReasonText" : "something",
  "Code" : "ABCD"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consecutively use **split**, **join** and **concat** functions to split the string, and then conditionally convert substrings and concatenate back all the pieces such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "information": {
        "*": {
          "ht": "=split('://',@(1,website))",
          "ws": "=split('/',@(1,ht[1]))",
          "last_ws": "=lastElement(@(1,ws))",
          "size_ws": "=size(@(1,ws))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "information": {
        "*": {
          "ws": {
            "0": { // for the first omponent of the array composed splitting  the sting by / characters
              "abcd": {
                "#abcd.india": "&5[&4].ws"
              },
              "xyxvv": {
                "#ind.hello": "&5[&4].ws"
              },
              "india.gateway.url": {
                "#india.ios.gw.hello": "&5[&4].ws"
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "v1": {
                "@(3,last_ws)": {//whenever match occurs with v1, set it to v2(occurence assumed only at this leaf level)
                  "#v2": "&6[&5].ws"
                }
              },
              "*": {
                "#ind.hello": "&5[&4].ws"
              }
            }
          },
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "information": {
        "*": {
          "ws": "=join('/',@(1,ws))",
          "website": "=concat(@(1,ht[0]),'://',@(1,ws))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "information": {
        "*": {
          "ht": "",
          "ws": "",
          "*ws": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: if website value comes - https://india.gateway.url/time/123/v1 and I want to replace "india.gateway.url/time/123" with "india.ios.gw.url/time/123/v2" then this will not happen with this jolt spec..

Comment: well , just edited @Smita

Comment: some confusion happened , just edited the output - only "http://india.gateway.url/time/123/v1" URL is something special - which should be converted to "http://india.ios.gw.url/time/123/v2" . I feel I need to write separate json transformation to handle this scenario. Any thoughts? Also the requirement is  that the website URL - may or may not contain prefix & suffix. Ideally if matching keyword found in string then replacement should happen..

Comment: let me know your thoughts